# How to convert year format "yy" as "yyyy" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to insert values from a table G0DM to G0RDM. The problem am facing is that date in Column DOJS in table GODM certain dates are specified as "01-01-00" format.. the year value is entered as "00" which needs to be displayed as 2000. I  tried changing the database entries manually but even though I tried the error keeps coming. Other columns which is related to dates also has the same problem. So changing it manually is so difficult..

My query:

```
INSERT INTO g0rdm
            (aud_number,
             short_code,
             entitlement_number,
             abbrevi,
             name,
             designation,
             person_charge,
             office_name,
             place,
             dob,
             dojs)
SELECT aud_number,
       short_code,
       entitlement_number,
       abbrevi,
       name,
       designation,
       person_charge,
       office_name,
       place,
       To_date(dob, 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
       To_date(dojs, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
FROM   g0dm;
```

The error message is :

```
SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range
```

Any solution?

Comment: what's your table structure like? [edit] your question and add in the table structure and some sample data

Comment: What data types are `g0dm.dob` and `g0dm.dojs` are they already defined as `DATE`? Using `to_date()` on a `DATE` column to convert it to a `DATE` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: hey Sathya.. the table contains almost 26 fields.. How to include it here..??

Comment: @ReenuRahman can you run below and provide the output for better understanding: select min(length(dob)), max(length(dob)), min(length(dojs)), max(length(dojs)) from g0dm;

Comment: Shantanu ..Min(length(dob)) returns : 8 Max(length(dob)) :10 Min(length(dojs)) : 8 Max(length(dojs)):11

Comment: @ReenuRahman - you have serious problem for g0dm.dob & g0dm.dobs. And we beleive these two are not in date format in table definition as rightly mentioned by other fellow member "Kim Berg Hansen". you can run this and share output: desc g0dm;

Comment: Yes, @Shanatanu is correct, you have problems ;-) Maybe using `RRRR` as in my updated answer helps, but since you have max length 11 for `dojs`, there must be some data in there that has yet a third format (not DD-MM-YY or DD-MM-YYYY) and that will be a problem.

Comment: I changed both G0DM and G0RDM dojs field datatype as varchar2.. and used   To_date(dob, 'dd-mm-rr'),
       To_date(dojs, 'dd-mm-rr')     . But the Dojs still contains "00" as year... no change in data...

Comment: @Shantanu desc g0dm produces following result                     Name               Null Type          
------------------ ---- ------------- 
OFFICE_NAME             VARCHAR2(500) 
DOB                     VARCHAR2(500) 
DOJS                    VARCHAR2(500) 
DOR                     VARCHAR2(500) 
NEW11                   VARCHAR2(500) 
GPL                     VARCHAR2(500) 
MOI                     VARCHAR2(500) 
CAP                     VARCHAR2(500) 
DATE111                 VARCHAR2(500) 
I omitted other data's as its too long to be used here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, as we now have some more info - here is a complete rewritten answer.

We have a source table:

```
create table g0dm (
   aud_number  number
 , dob         VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

The source table is populated from a CSV file and the date-of-birth is badly written input sometimes with 2 digits for year, sometimes with 4 digits for year. Therefore the datatype in this table is VARCHAR2.

Here is some sample data inserts simulating the import from the CSV file:

```
insert into g0dm values (1 , '01-01-1900');
insert into g0dm values (2 , '01-02-1949');
insert into g0dm values (3 , '01/03.1950');
insert into g0dm values (4 , '01-04-2000');
insert into g0dm values (5 , '01.05.00');
insert into g0dm values (6 , '01-06-49');
insert into g0dm values (7 , '01-07-50');
insert into g0dm values (8 , '1/8-2015');
insert into g0dm values (9 , '01.SEP.2016');
insert into g0dm values (10, '01/10. 2017');
insert into g0dm values (11, '1-NOV   2018');
insert into g0dm values (12, '01  DEC  2019');
commit;
```

Then we have the target table:

```
create table g0rdm (
   aud_number  number
 , dob         DATE
);
```

In the target table we want the date-of-birth as a true DATE, so that we can use it properly in the application. (As a DATE column this does *not* have any format - this contains always century, year, month, date, hour, minute and second.)

To copy the data from the source to the target and convert the dob from VARCHAR2 to DATE along the way, we can use an INSERT statement that uses TO_DATE:

```
insert into g0rdm (aud_number, dob)
select aud_number
     , to_date(dob, 'DD-MM-RRRR')
  from g0dm;

commit;
```

By using RRRR format for the year rather than YY, YYYY or RR, that can handle both 2-digit and 4-digit years in the source data. We can see the result by selecting what did get inserted into target table g0rdm:

```
select aud_number
     , to_char(dob, 'DD. Mon YYYY') dob_as_string
  from g0rdm
 order by aud_number;

AUD_NUMBER DOB_AS_STRIN
---------- ------------
         1 01. Jan 1900
         2 01. Feb 1949
         3 01. Mar 1950
         4 01. Apr 2000
         5 01. May 2000
         6 01. Jun 2049
         7 01. Jul 1950
         8 01. Aug 2015
         9 01. Sep 2016
        10 01. Oct 2017
        11 01. Nov 2018
        12 01. Dec 2019

12 rows selected.
```

See aud_number 5, 6 and 7 to see how RRRR handled the 2-digit years.

The documentation explains date/time format models: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

In particular it explains the RR (and thus RRRR) handling of 2-digit years: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i116004

(As a side note - it might be possible for you to skip having two tables and just import the CSV straight into the target table having DATE columns. It depends on how you actually do the importing, whether your import tool accepts specifying the date format as DD-MM-RRRR. If you use external tables or sql loader you can do that. Otherwise a solution like above can work.)

Comment: returns error while 'dd-mm-rr' is given...SQL Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: Is column `dojs` a VARCHAR2 or a DATE column? Since you are using `to_date` on it, I assume it is VARCHAR2. If `RR` fails with that error, then I guess you have some data in the VARCHAR2 column that has 4 digits for year?

Comment: Kim Berg Hansen.. DOJS is declared as DATE.. I tried varchar2 earlier.. but later converted to DATE... In DOJS some entries are in the format "09-08-2004" ... i.e dd-mm-yyyy.... some entries are entered wrongly... "03-08-00" .. I need to  convert all the entries that ends with "00" to "2000"

Comment: That cannot be. A `DATE` column does not have a format. `DATE` columns *always* contain the complete year, month, day, hour, minute and second information in an internal format. If it is a `DATE` column it cannot be true that some has 4 digits and other has 2 digits, that is impossible. Format of a `DATE` column happens only when you select it - either it defaults to whatever format your client uses, or the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting of your session, or you can use `TO_CHAR(the_date_col, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` to display the content of the `DATE` in whatever format you want to display.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me. You have a source table (or view) called `g0dm` with a column `dojs`. Is *that* column a DATE? The destination table called `g0rdm` I can see that the `dojs` column is probably a `DATE`.

Comment: actully gordm contains datatype date while godm contains varchar2.. i wil change it and have a try

Comment: I changed both G0DM and G0RDM dojs field datatype as varchar2.. and used   To_date(dob, 'dd-mm-rr'),
       To_date(dojs, 'dd-mm-rr')     . But the Dojs still contains "00" as year... no change in data...

Comment: Naturally. You start with G0DM.dojs as VARCHAR2. Then you use TO_DATE to convert that explicitly to a DATE datatype. Then you insert the DATE into G0RDM.dojs, which you now changed to a VARCHAR2, and that means Oracle implicitly converts the DATE back to VARCHAR2 using whatever NLS_DATE_FORMAT your session is using. I'll update the answer with some more details - comments are not good for this.

Comment: ok @Kim I usually imports the data as a csv file.. even if I declare dojs as Date datatype.. data loading fails it changes only when I update the datatype as varchar2.. that is another problem... I tried that too... tried both the datatypes..

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH ...I gt the values rgt...when I use to_char seperately the date format is displayed as DD. Mon YYYY format 18. Sep 2000.. while if to_date(dojs, 'DD/MM/RRRR') is used.. the date still gets displayed as 18-SEP-00.. but dis will do fine thank u :)